# Can't get @font-face working within a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, font-face

Is there a default location for where I should be storing the fonts?
Within rails I can't get the font to load, whereas with the 'font kit' downloaded from fontsquirrel.com where the font,css and sample html in the same folder will work.

this is my css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'RalewayThin';
src: url('fonts/raleway_thin.eot');
src: url('fonts/raleway_thin.ttf') format('truetype');
```

}

the fonts folder is in /public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my style sheets I almost always have to have urls start with `../` to get the correct path.  You might want to try

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'RalewayThin';
  src: url('../fonts/raleway_thin.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/raleway_thin.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

If that doesn't work, you might want to use the developer tools in your browser to see if and what url the browse is using to get the font files.

Answer (score 0):

hi your font name is different check this

font-family: 'RalewayThin';
src: local('Raleway Thin')

Comment: font-family: can be named anything,
src: local is what the font is called on the end-users local machine if they have it